# Password checker java program

Tags: java

I am trying to create a program that will check the password of the user. I want the program to end once the user gets it correct but if not I want it to ask only 4 times.

Problem: even if you do get the password correctly the program keeps on asking guess the password. And if you get it wrong it will ask incorrectly. How can I fix this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class HowToAdd {
    public static void main (String [] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        int trys = 0;
        String password=null;
        do{
            System.out.println("Guess the password");
            password = input.next();

            if(password.equalsIgnoreCase("Password")){
                System.out.println("Great job");
            }else{
                System.out.println("Try again");
                input.next();
                trys++;
            }
        }while(trys<2);
        System.out.println("Try again later!");

        input.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Passwords are generally case sensitive. You should consider switching out `.equalsIgnoreCase()` with `.equals()`.

Comment: @user3453661 Look at my solution below, it should give you exactly what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add a break:

```
if(password.equalsIgnoreCase("Password")){
 System.out.println("Great job");
 break;
}
```

Comment: You don't handle extra password question after loop.

Comment: @user2784201 sorry i didn't understood your question. :)

Comment: I mean in your case "Try again later!" message will always appear disregard the password :)

Comment: @user2784201 ohh, yeah you are right,didn't saw that line, although i just posted a snippet but i should have told the OP about it, maybe he figured that out himself that's why didn't complained, by the way we need just need to put that line in a if block and check the value of trys :)

Answer (score 1):

Not only did I add a break to fix the problem of not leaving the loop when correct password is entered but I added a couple of other things to help you out see below:

```
 public static void main (String [] args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    int trys = 0;
    String password=null;
    System.out.println("Guess the password:");
    while(trys<2)
    {
        password = input.next();

        if(password.equalsIgnoreCase("Password")){
            System.out.println("Great job");
            break;
        }else{
            trys++;
            if(trys != 2)
            {
                System.out.println("Try again:");
            }
        }
    }
    if(trys == 2)
    {
        System.out.println("Try again later!");
    }

    input.close();
}
```

Try this it will break out of the loop if it is correct using the `break;` statement.  Also it will only display guess a password the first try then try again after that.  Also it won't say try again later if they guessed right because it checks if they guessed wrong twice.

Comment: Thank you very much. Did you run it because I get something wrong with this i mean it works but the logic is wrong

Comment: @user3453661 I edited it try that see if that fixes what you were talking about.  I think you meant because it says try again then try again later back to back this will check if there have already been 2 guesses and not display try again if there has.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it with a `break` keyword, like so :

```
        if(password.equalsIgnoreCase("Password")){
            System.out.println("Great job");
            break;
        }
```

The `break` is explained here :

[Branching Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html)

Comment: minus-1 , this muy terrible muy muy

Comment: PLUS1 WONDFRULWONDFRULWONDFRUL

Answer (score 0):

What you need to implement can be done without using `break` statements.
Try to look at the flow of my codes.

```
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    int tries=0;
    String pw = "";

    System.out.println("Guess the password");
    pw = scn.nextLine();

    while(!pw.equalsIgnoreCase("Password") && tries < 3){
        tries++;
        System.out.println("Try again");
        pw = scn.nextLine();            
    }

    if(tries >= 3)
        System.out.println("Try again later!");
    else
        System.out.println("Great job!");
```

**TEST RUN 1:**

```
Guess the password
1st try
Try again
2nd try
Try again
3rd try
Try again
last try
Try again later!
```

**TEST RUN 2:**

```
Guess the password
password
Great job!
```

Comment: Something also wrong with this program that I quickly found as soon as I ran it                                                                            Guess the password
hello
Try again
hello
Try again
hello
Try again
password
Try again later!

Comment: Guess the password
hello
Try again
hello
Try again
hello
Try again
password
Try again later!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another variant of code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int trys = 0;
    String password = null;
    // create variable for a number of tries
    int numberOfCheks = 4;
    do {
        System.out.println("Guess the password");
        password = input.nextLine();

        if (password.equalsIgnoreCase("Password")) {
            System.out.println("Great job");
            break;
        } else if (++trys == numberOfCheks) {
           //Break if you've used all your tries 
            System.out.println("Try again later!");
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Try again");
            // input.next(); - Useless. You don't handle it. Removed
        }
    //There is already tries number check. So 'true' can be used as the condition.
    } while (true); 
    input.close();
}
```

Comment: There is something wrong with this for because since you put the guess the password in the do while loop it will keep asking "guess the password try again" and this is unnecessary due to the fact that at the end of the program when the loop exists as false the loop will stay say guess the password

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your comment. This sentence is too long. This loop works 4 times, if you put an incorrect password. If your password is correct the loop immediately stops. Have you tested it?

Comment: actually sorry i tested it out again must of been a error i made when running it

Comment: Maybe you try to get input sting with spaces?  `Scanner.next()` method returns the next complete **token** from this scanner. A complete token is preceded and followed by input that matches the **delimiter pattern**. Fixed to `nextLine()`